# Installing Eddybeacon

Tags: google-api, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, eddystone

As far as I understand eddybeacon (just released by Google) is effectively a new 'operating system' for Bluetooth 4.0 Low energy devices (iBeacons). I have been experimenting with iBeacons for sometime now and want to try out a few things with eddybeacon. Has anyone had a go with it yet? I've read a few sites and they say it can be installed to some devices... Can anyone share how to do this?

Comment: [Estimote](http://estimote.com/indoor/) saved me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start out by playing with Eddystone, you have a couple of options:

1. You can use a software transmitter.  Just [download my free Locate App in the Google Play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate) which will both act as an Eddystone transmitter and decode other Eddystone-compatible beacons in the vicinity.    Google also has posted an Android app that can transmit the Eddystone-UID frame [here](https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/eddystone-uid/tools/txeddystone-uid), but you have to compile it yourself.
2. You can get a few hardware beacons for testing with a Developer Kit from Radius Networks (my company) [here](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/eddystone-devkit).

Once you have a transmitter, you can try writing some software to work with it.  Here's a tutorial I wrote on [how to build a basic Eddystone-capable Android app.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/07/14/building-apps-with-eddystone.html)

One other thing that might be useful is an Eddystone detector tool.  You can use the free Android [Locate app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate) to detect and decode all of the frames transmitted by Eddystone.

Answer (score 1):

So:

1. **Eddystone** is a specification for Bluetooth Smart (usually just called BLE) devices to behave like beacons — it defines the Bluetooth frames and content they need to broadcast to be seen as beacons.
2. iBeacon is not a generic term. iBeacon is actually Apple's specification for Bluetooth beacons. Eddystone and iBeacon are both examples of beacon specifications for BLE devices.
3. There are a few ways to get started with Eddystone beacons.

   a. A number of hardware manufacturers sell developer kits that will let you get started with Eddystone beacons right away, and there is plenty of example software out, either from those vendors, or from the google pages on GitHub — [github.com/google/eddystone](http://github.com/google/eddystone) and [github.com/google/beacon-platform](http://github.com/google/beacon-platform).

   b. Some people have had good luck with Arduinos and Raspberry Pis. You can see an Arduino [example here](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-BLEPeripheral) (Note: I have no idea how well that project works, I've just seen it used a few times.)